# Service is missing... Something.

Tags: c#, service, winlogon

Alright, so I'm creating a windows service that will start and stop my rendering executable based on whether or not a user is logged in. I have already determined that I want to run the exe from a service, and know it will run in a secure desktop with no gui. That is not a problem for me.

What is a problem is that my service, when I tell it to start, instantly starts. I think that means I'm missing some sort of loop or event handler or SOMETHING, but I have no clue what. This is the first service I've tried to program. As there seems to be no way to debug a service effectively, I was hoping to get some input from the brilliant minds here.

Any input would be very much appreciated! Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace SessionService
{
    public partial class renderServ : ServiceBase
    {
        private readonly ManagementClass _wmiComputerSystem = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
        private Process process;
        Boolean isRunning;

        public renderServ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");

            isRunning = false;
        }

        public void OnUserLogin()
        {
            /*if (isRunning == true)
            {
                process.Kill();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }*/
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public void OnUserLogoff()
        {
            if (isRunning == false)
            {
                process.Start();
                process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
            }
            isRunning = true;
        }

        protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
        {
            base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);

            switch (changeDescription.Reason)
            {
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                    {
                        OnUserLogin();
                    } break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
                    {
                        OnUserLogoff();
                    } break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
                    {
                        OnUserLogoff();
                    } break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:
                    {
                        OnUserLogin();
                    } break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you start your service, then attach the debugger (DEBUG -> Attach to process -> choose your service). You can step through the code as you would any other app.

Comment: If you don't want any UI, why on earth are you using any part of `System.Windows.Forms`? What you should have in `OnStart` is code that creates any threads and/or timers (or e.g. WCF hosts) and then returns. The thread that calls `OnStart` doesn't "belong" to you, and you need to *return* from the `OnStart` method before your service is considered to be started.

Comment: Ah, so if I create a timer that loops (I saw some examples of that in another service) then the service should start?

Comment: Yes, the important thing is that `OnStart` needs to return. `Application.Run()`, for example, only returns when something else calls `Application.Exit()`

Comment: Services run in session 0, the isolated session where services run.  Nobody logs in or out, the screen saver never runs, nobody locks the work station.  So the events never fire.